# How to solve this destroying problem in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d

I want to destroy the ball when it collides with ground, but it doesnt work for me

Here is the part of the script

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

thanks, have a great day

Comment: Does the ball GameObject has the tag `Ball`?

Comment: Yes, it does, I just checked

Comment: Can you print above your `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")` the tag like that: `Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.tag)`?

Comment: no, it still doesnt work                                                                                                   
 if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            Debug.Log(collision.gameObject.tag);

            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }

Comment: What does it prints in the Unity console?

Comment: nothing, not even an error

Comment: The associated script with the `OnCollisionEnter` method is attached to the ground?

Comment: yes, do I have to put the script on the ball?

Comment: No it's fine like that but remember to add colliders to both ball and ground.

Comment: You may use a `Circle Collider 2D` for the ball and a `Terrain collider` for the ground.

Comment: Oh, ill try that

Comment: When I added terrain collider, it doesnt even react with the ball

Comment: A tutorial that can help you with colliders: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbPiCgCkHTE

Comment: Thanks, for the video, but my colliders work, they just dont react so that the ball gets destroyed when it touches the ground. Im making a phone game, and i wanted to add death like in doodle jump, so i added the ground, disabled its mesh renderer, attached the ground to the camera, and camera to player. Do you know any other way to achieve this kind of death in unity?

Comment: You can also try to reverse the logic by moving the `OnCollisionEnter` from the ground to the ball and check if the ball hits the ground.

Comment: thanks for all the support, it still doesnt work, ill search for it on YouTube, have a great week ;)

Comment: If you still suffer this bug, add screenshots of from your inspector of ball and ground

Comment: Did you remember to put the script on the ground object in the scene? Also make sure the tag uses the same casing as your code, it's case sensitive.

Comment: Just for laughs, try using **collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ball")**.  Probably won't make a difference but just try it out.

Comment: Is the method even invoked? Because its either your code or the colliders.